# How to control HOST systemd service inside pid namespace

Tags: systemd, docker, namespace

*Note: this is not about to run systemd inside namespace/container*

I need to control some service, from inside a namespace/container, but `systemctl` returns "Failed to connect to bus: No data available".

How to do this? Maybe I must mount something into the container?

The namespace/container may be a simple `unshare --pid` or a complete docker container.